# Shockwave not responding in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, flash

When browsing in Google chrome, I get an error message

> The exception unknown software exception (0x40000015) occurred in the
>   application at location 0x0025bf18.

I get a pop-up message later saying that the Shockwave plugin is not responding.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing Chrome (even by clearing my browsing data while uninstalling) and still the error persists.

There are 2 instances of Shockwave that I could see in my Chrome by typing `chrome://plugins`. I've tried disabling either of those alternatively too. This prevents me from browsing a lot of sites including FB and Stackoverflow through my favorite browser.  I don't have any problem when I work from Internet Explorer.

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. I'll let you know if I find anything that can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I gave previously was just a temporary fix and didn't solve the actual problem. I went here: [Shockwave Flash Crashes in Google Chrome](http://www.howtogeek.com/103292/how-to-fix-shockwave-flash-crashes-in-google-chrome/) and it gave me an answer. Basically, there are conflicting Flash files within Chrome and one of them has to be disabled by looking at the Chrome plugins. In the URL, type chrome://plugins.